# re-map local TFS copy

Tags: tfs

I am not sure how this can be done. I searched internet to find a solution but did not fine any.

I had a copy mapped to my local folder of a TFS project. But, somehow the mapping is removed (I do not know why), and right now showing "Not Mapped" in Server Control Explorer.

I see that I still have local physical copy. But, I have pending changes in that copy.

Anybody can help how can I re-map to the same local copy folder and then check in my pending changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, backup your pending changes to another folder.

Then, click on the "Not Mapped" and map again the local folder with the files.

When VS will ask you if download the files, press "Yes".

Now, VS will say that you have a conflicts (because your previous changes), so resolve the conflicts the choose "Keep Local File Contents".

[image]

Now you can check-in the changes to TFS (those changes are your "Pending Changes").

Comment: This looks more convincing. I asked to support guys at Microsoft, they reverted with:


"We have see this in a few cases.
Copy the code to a safe location first and then getting the last version from Azure DevOps is recommended.
 
Once the code is checked out, the files with changes can be replaced and then checked it again.
 
I hope this helps resolve the issue. Regret the inconvenience cause."